# Spatial Branch and Bound Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science, mathematical-optimization

I would like to know the time complexity of the Spatial Branch and Bound method? I am confused what the Big O notation of the spatial branch and bound would look like since it is a recursive method.

Comment: For solving integer linear problems? It's exponential in the worst case, since ILP is NP complete.

Comment: Thank you, Paul Hankin. It is for solving integer linear problems.